# ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined. While trying to implement the keras model

Tags: keras

I had the following error while trying to implement a keras model:

> "ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined
>   (got (None, None, 512). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or
>   "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model."

What could be the problem here?

```
from keras import applications
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense

weights_path = '../keras/examples/vgg16_weights.h5'
top_model_weights_path = 'fc_model.h5'
img_width, img_height = 240, 320

train_data_dir = 'datasetmini/train'
validation_data_dir = 'datasetmini/VALIDATION'
nb_train_samples = nb_train_samples
nb_validation_samples = nb_validation_samples
epochs = epochs
batch_size = batch_size

model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
print('Model loaded.')

top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
top_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)


model.add(top_model)

for layer in model.layers[:25]:
    layer.trainable = False


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Unable to fine tune Keras vgg16 model - input shape issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5257). It turns out that one should specify `input_shape` when loading the keras pre-trained model.

And also `keras.engine.training.Model` cannot `add` new layers, so one should build a new `keras.engine.sequential.Sequential` model and then use `add`.

A MWE:

```
from keras import applications
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras import optimizers
import numpy as np

img_width, img_height = 240, 320
model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
print('Model loaded.')

top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten())
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
#top_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)

##this will fail
##AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'add'
#model.add(top_model)

new_model = Sequential()
new_model.add(model)
new_model.add(top_model)

for layer in new_model.layers[:25]:
    layer.trainable = False

new_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 8
X = np.random.randn(batch_size,240,320,3)
Y = np.random.randn(batch_size, 1)

new_model.train_on_batch(X, Y)
```

Comment: Thank you so much but still i got an error "Error when checking input: expected vgg16_input to have shape (320, 240, 3) but got array with shape (240, 320, 3)"

Comment: That's because the order of `(img_width, img_height)` is reversed when you use `train_datagen.flow_from_directory` and `test_datagen.flow_from_directory `.